# Subgroups of order $p^2$ present in a abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-product

How many subgroups of order $p^2$ does the abelian group $\mathbb{Z_{p^3}} \times \mathbb{Z_{p^2}}$have ?

Comment: First step in answering is to ask how many non-isomorphic groups of order $p^2$ are there, and what is their structure?

Comment: It will either be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}$ or be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_p}$ x $\mathbb{Z_p}$

Comment: Good. That should help you to find the number of instances of each of those as subgroups of your group.

Comment: This question is not as trivial as it seems, since a subgroup of $A\times B$ need not to be in the form of $H\times K$. As an easy example, $Z_p\times Z_p$ has $p+1$ subgroup isomorphic to $Z_p$.(not 2).

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Your example is not that difficult to work out. Its $p^2$ - $1$ non identity elements partitioned into $p$ - $1$ parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**lemma:** if there are $n$ elements of order $d$ in $G$, there are $\dfrac n {\phi(d)}$ cyclic subgroup of order $d$ where $\phi$ is Euler phi function.

By using this lemma and counting the elements of $G$ with order $p^2$, I found $p^2+p$ cyclic subgroup of $G$. The method is simple but calculation is boring.

Here is the calculation.

Let $G=Z_{p^2}\times Z_{p^3}$ and $a$ be an element of $G$ with order $p^2$ then $a=(x,y)$ where $lcd(|x||,|y|=p^2)$ then at least one of the order is $p^2$.

**case 1:** $|x|=p^2$

$\phi(p^2)=p^2-p$ if $|y|=p$ we have $p-1$ such $y$ as a result we get $(p-1)(p^2-p)$ elements in $G$.

if $|y|=p^2$ then we get $(p^2-p)$ such $y$ as a result  $(p^2-p)^2$ elements in $G$.

$if |y|=1$ then we must have $y=e$ so $(p^2-p)$ elements in $G$.

In total, we have $p^2(p^2-p)$ elements in $G$.

**case 2:** if $|y|=p^2$ then it is enough to calculate when $|x|=p$ and $|x|=e$ .(we already calculated the case $|x|=|y|=p^2$).

Wits same manner we get $p(p^2-p)$ elements in $G$.

From case $1$ and case $2$ we get $(p^2+p)(p^2-p)$ elements of order $p^2$ in $G$.

Thus the number of the cyclic subgroup of $G$ with order $p^2$ is $\dfrac {(p^2+1)(p^2-1)}{\phi(p^2)}=p^2+p$

**Edit:**
Notice that the group $\mathbb Z_p \times Z_p$ has $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$.

$\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ has $p-1$ elements of order $p$ and $Z_{p^3}$ has $p-1$ elements of order $p$.

and $G$ have $(p-1)p$+$1(p-1)=p^2-1$ elements of order $p$.

So $G$ has unique subgroup which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p $.

In total, $G$ has $p^2+p+1$ subgroup of order $p^2$.

Comment: I will edit my answer to comlete the answer.

Comment: @user119065: I hope the lemma used in the answer is clear for you.

Comment: Can you explain how the lemma is working ?

Comment: A cyclic group with order $d$ has $\phi(d)$ generaters and of course all of them has order $d$. If there are $k$ cyclic subgroup of order $d$ in $G$ then there are $k\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$ in $G$. (Notice that even if the cyclic subgroups may intersects, generators  will not be in intersection. This lemma does not even require $G$ is abelian ). Example: In $S_4$, there are $(4-1)!=6$  elements of order $4$ so $\dfrac 6 {\phi(4)}=3$ cyclic subgroup of order $4$.

Comment: @Jacob111: It seems that you did not take $\langle (2,6) \rangle$ and $\langle (2,2)\rangle$. $p^2+p$ is the number of the cyclic subgroup of order $p^2$. There is also a noncyclic subgroup of order $p^2$. Thus the total number is $p^2+p+1$.

Comment: @mesel Ah, of course. Thanks for clarifying  - I will delete my comment.

Comment: I also did not understand the reason of the downvote?

Comment: Sorry, but I am interested in the proof of the lemma. Could you demonstrate it, please?

Comment: Let $k_d$ be set of elements of $order $d$ in $G$. Define an equivalence relation on $k_d$ by setting, $x\sim y$ if and only if $\langle x \rangle = \langle y \rangle$.(Show that it is really an equivalence relation.) Then the formula follows easily.

Comment: Maybe you mean the following: Let $S=\{g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n\}$ the set of elements of group $G$ of order $d$. Define the relation on $S$ by $x\sim y$ iff $\langle x\rangle=\langle y\rangle$. Then it is easy to check that this is an equivalence relation and each equivalence class has $\varphi(d)$ element. Hence the number of such classes is $n/\varphi(d)$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Number of such classes is also equal to number of the cyclic subgroups of order $d$. By the way, you may obtain a summation fotmula $$|G|=\sum s_d  \varphi(d)$$ where $s_d$ is the number of the cyclic subgroups of $G$ and $d$ runs over the divisor of order of G. In particular, we may get $\sum_{d \mid n}\varphi(d)= n$ when G is a cyclic group of order $n$, which is well known in number thoery.

Comment: @mesel I am lost when you computed $p(p-1)+1(p-1) = p^2-1$. For $\mathbb Z_{p^3} $ and $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ you have $p - 1$ element of order $ p$. Wouldn't that make you to get $p(p-1)+p(p-1) = 2p^2-2p$?